# Sketch the Graph of $-x^3+27$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Not sure if this is the right way to solve.

The question ask to sketch the graph of each function by transforming the graph of an appropriate function of the form $y=x^n$. Indicate all $x$- and $y$- intercepts on each graph.

Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $-x^3$ is the reflection about y-axis of $x^3$
2. $-x^3+27$ is just a transformation in positive y direction
3. to get the x-intercept we put $y=0$ and then $$-x^3+27=0\implies -(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)=0\implies x=3$$

[image]

Comment: How do I get the the x intercept for a cube?

Comment: So my x intercepts would be x=3,x=(-/+)3 + (5)/(2)?

Comment: x intercepts are the real solutions only

Comment: your factorization is incorrect

Comment: Okay. I see you can't square root a negative number. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So do you accept it

Comment: Yes I do except that your solution is correct. Thanks.

Comment: I mean do you mark it as an answer

Comment: I have the answers in back of my textbook. However, I did not understand how to find the x intercept. Thanks once again for your help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: My dear there is an icon on the left of my answer below the down arrow, click on it means you accept it as an answer

Comment: I need more reputation points, sorry.

Comment: this does not decrease your reputation If you did so, you do increase my reputation only in this site and encourage me to answer many questions

Comment: Whatever you accept my answer or not, you have to know that both upvotes of questions and answers and acceptance of answers do not decrease your reputation points. Only downvotes do. So it is nice to accept and upvote answers and questions to encourage others

Answer (score 1):

To get a more accurate graph, you'll also want to find the $x$-intercept(x): where your function value $f(x) = 0$. $$27-x^3 = 0 \iff x^3 - 27 = 0 \iff (x-3)(x^2 + 3x + 9) = 0$$

This will happen at $x = 3$. ($x^2 + 3x + 9$ has no real roots, so there is one and only one real-valued x-intercept.) So you can graph the point $(3, 0)$ on your graph, as well.

*Note: your factoring is a little bit off.

Comment: Yes, I notice that. Nonetheless, I see you got rid of the negative sign in front of the x by just inverting the two terms. What is that called? Or is that just your method of getting rid of the negative?

Comment: I did that simply in the case when we set $27 - x^3$ equal to zero to find the $x$-intercept(s). $27 - x^3 = 0 \iff -(x^3 - 27) = 0 \iff x^3 - 27 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Semsem has provided the graphs; here is how you would find the intercepts.

For the $y$ intercept, this is just when $x$ is evaluated at $0$, so plug in $x = 0$ to get $27$.

For the $x$ intercepts, factor the expression $-x^3 + 27$. Note that the factorization you provided is incorrect, you forgot to distribute the negative. The correct answer would be $-(x^3 - 27) = -(x - 3)(x^2 + 3x + 9)$. Then use zero product property and quadratic formula.

Comment: Should one always take the negative sign out first when factoring? Is that a good rule?

Comment: If you're more comfortable with having the leading coefficient be positive (which most people are), then I would suggest you do.